# How to respond to BLE GATT write request with "invalid attribute value"?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I have a BLE characteristic that shall represent a switch, hence a boolean value. My intention is to give it a fixed size of "1 byte", and when read, `0` means `false`, `1` means `true`. I want this characteristic to be readable and writable.

Since the value can be written, I want to validate that only one of those two values is written to the characteristic. Any other values are invalid.

The [Bluetooth Core Specification v5.3](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification-5-3/) specifies in Volume 3, Part F, chapter 3.4.5.1 "ATT_WRITE_REQ" (page 1443):

> If the attribute value has a fixed length and the requested attribute value
> parameter length is greater than the length of the attribute value then the
> server shall respond with an ATT_ERROR_RSP PDU with the Error Code
> parameter set to Invalid Attribute Value Length (0x0D).

This code `0x0D` is also mentioned on page 1423 in a table of ATT error codes. So when the client attempts to write more than 1 byte to the characterstic, I reject the write request with that error code `0x0D`, and the correct error message appears in *nRF Connect* for example.

What I cannot find is if there is any recommended way to respond something that conveys an "invalid value" or "value out of range" error kind; in my case, that would be the response to any 1-byte-values other than `0x00` or `0x01`, like `0x0A` for example.

I see that table 3.4 on pages 1422f contains error codes for the *ATT_ERROR_RSP* PDU, `0x13` "Value Not Allowed" being one of them. `0x13` is however not listed as valid error code in response to an ATT_WRITE_REQ (table 3.44, page 1458).

The concept of "invalid argument" appears so fundamental to me that I don't trust my understanding it is not covered by the standard codes already.

But the only somewhat matching pre-defined **and valid** error code would be `0x06` "Request Not Supported", but that one is so widely used for all kinds of requests that I don't think it's meant to be used here.

Is it really up to me to pick a custom error code from the "Application Error" range? If not, which pre-defined error code should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Background**

Note that the error codes that are defined and discussed in the ATT chapter are mainly ATT protocol related error codes. The ATT protocol's task is to make sure that the request opcode is supported, the handle is valid, the permissions are acceptable, a sent value conforms to the maximum length requirements etc. The ATT protocol does not inspect or validate the contents of the individual bytes. That is the task of a "higher level specification", i.e. in practice GATT or a GATT service. You should therefore definitely not use ATT protocol specific error codes such as "Request Not Supported" since that refers to that an ATT operation is not implemented.

Keep in mind that the Bluetooth specification is written and maintained by a huge amount of companies and organizations who can propose not so always well thought out changes that after a (quick) review can get incorporated into the standard. Also since different Bluetooth SIG GATT services are made by different people, these people might have different opinions on which error codes should be used due to the lack of good ones properly defined by the core standard.

Let's go back to Bluetooth v4.0, when BLE was introduced. Here we can read that the only valid error codes for Write Requests are "Application Error" error codes (0x80-0xff) beyond some ATT protocol specific error codes. The ATT chapter does not specify the meaning for specific Application Error codes but instead says they are defined in a "higher layer specification".

In the GATT chapter of the 4.0 specification, we can read:

> If the Characteristic Value that is written is the wrong size, or has an invalid value as defined by the profile, then the value shall not be written and an Error Response shall be sent with the Error Code set to Application Error by the server.

Opening up various GATT service specifications from Bluetooth SIG, custom application error codes are defined in a table with the corresponding meaning for this service and how the specific error code is used. One example is the Alert Notification Service, where one code is defined as "command not allowed". Another example is the HTTP Proxy Service which defines the application errors "Invalid Request" when the URI, HTTP Header or body is incorrect, and "Network Not Available" when no network connection is available. For the Physical Activity Monitor Service there is one error code "Invalid Type" that is used when the Type value is in the RFU range. Otherwise, the early defined services back in 2011 often ignore the case when an invalid value is written and do not specify how that should be handled. Take the Link Loss service for example where the alert level can be one of three different levels. It specifies how the device should act upon a disconnection for (only) the three different levels. It does not mention that a value out of range should be rejected when written and it does not specify what should happen upon disconnection if the written value was out of range.

To solve the mess a few "Common Profile and Service Error Codes" were added in Bluetooth 4.1 and listed in the Core Specification Supplement. Two of particular interest are the following:

> 2.1 OUT OF RANGE (0xFF)
> The Out of Range error code is used when an attribute value is out of range as defined by a profile or service specification.

> 2.4 WRITE REQUEST REJECTED (0xFC)
> The Write Request Rejected error code is used when a requested write operation cannot be fulfilled for reasons other than permissions. Note: This differs from the “Write Not Permitted” error response in Vol 3, Part F, Section 3.4.1.1 (ATT), which is intended when the write operation cannot be fulfilled due to permissions.

Lately defined services, such as the Emergency Configuration Service, has a big section in its introduction that when a client writes a value that is RFU, the server should generally "reject" the write, which I assume means use the error code above. The server can also, when specified, ignore individual RFU bits or whole RFU values, in case that would be more relevant.

In the ATT chapter of Bluetooth 4.1, the Application Error range has now been decreased from 0x80-0xff to 0x80-0x9f. The range 0xa0-0xdf is now RFU and 0xe0-0xff is allocated for "Common Profile and Service Error Codes". Apart from being breaking changes, they did two mistakes:

1. They forgot to include "Common Profile and Service Error Codes" in the list of allowed Error Response codes for relevant corresponding request methods "Attribute Request and Response Summary".
2. They forgot to change the text in the GATT chapter about how to handle a written value that is the wrong size or is invalid as defined by the profile. It still says (only) that an "Application Error" shall be sent. It should mention the possibility of "Common Profile and Service Error Codes" as well.

Since neither of the ATT nor GATT standards mention these new error codes as being valid to use for any of the Write methods, they are technically never allowed to be used...

The first mistake was fixed first in version 5.3. The second mistake has still not been fixed as of the latest version (5.3).

In Bluetooth 5.1, a Client Supported Features characteristic was added to the Generic Attribute Profile Service. This contains a bitfield that can be written by the client. If a client has ever written 1 to a bit, it may not later write a 0 to the same bit. Since the team defining this missed that the error code "Write Request Rejected" exists, or didn't think it was good enough, they invented a new error code "Value Not Allowed" which, according to my interpretation, means that the value is in range but in this situation not allowed. Here I think they made a mistake adding this as an error code as part of the ATT standard, rather than as a "Common Profile and Service Error Code". Again, they made the same mistake as before, i.e. forgot to update the table of valid error codes for the different ATT request methods as well as updating the Write section in the GATT chapter that this error code may be used when a value is not allowed.

This new Value Not Allowed error code is used in the Microphone Control Service. It has a Mute characteristic (readable, writable, notifiable) which can contain Not Muted, Muted, Disabled or RFU. A client may only write Not Muted or Muted, otherwise the server shall return "Write Not Allowed". Only the server can hence set the value to "Disabled".

So due to the lack of a clearly defined "invalid value" error defined in the first place in Bluetooth 4.0, the various specifications are not consistent how to handle the case when a written value is out of range or RFU. Some services ignore values that are RFU, some use the "Write Not Allowed" error code, some use the "Write Request Rejected" error code, some use service-defined application error codes and you also have the "Out Of Range" error code.

**Conclusion**

For your case, I would probably go with the "Out Of Range" 0xff error code when 1 byte is written, but the byte is out of range, since it best describes the error and is probably the most helpful one, rather than a custom application error code or a generic not allowed/rejected error code. Clients complying to Bluetooth 4.1 or newer will see this 0xff as "Out Of Range", while clients complying to Bluetooth 4.0 will see this 0xff as an Application Error code.

Comment: So my intuition that there MUST be some kind of common value for this error kind was correct. And now that I have had reason to look specifically for those "common error codes", I have found all the information in the Core v5.3 and CSS v10. I had seen them but since I didn't associate them with what I was looking for, and it was outsourced to a different document, my in-file-searches for "out of range" yielded no results (just hits for literal "out of range" as in real-world distances). So yes, mentioning them in the actual text with and example might've helped me.

Comment: Even though I know the answer now, I keep coming back to this question and re-read your beautiful answer. It's perfect, providing in depth knowledge as well as the solution. Thank you again.